# Bevor mit und ohne Verneinung

Tags: subordinate-clause, negation

Vorhin wurde [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26371/15318) gestellt, die folgenden Beispielsatz enthielt:

> Ich kann nicht ins Bett gehen, bevor ich nicht allen helfe.

Meine spontane Reaktion war, dass da ein *nicht* reinmuss. Ich hab angefangen, die Antwort zu formulieren, und war mir plötzlich gar nicht mehr so sicher. Denn ich glaube, dass der Satz auch folgendermaßen möglich sein könnte:

> Ich kann nicht ins Bett gehen, bevor ich allen helfe.

Hiergilt hat im Chat zwar behauptet, [das klinge wie »Aufgabe verfehlt«](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25066114#25066114) aber ungrammatisch kommt es mir auch nicht vor. Ist das weglassen des *nicht* möglich, und wenn ja, verschiebt sich dadurch die Bedeutung?

Comment: Perfekt würde ich noch einigermaßen akzeptieren (_bevor ich allen geholfen habe_), aber so geht’s nicht. Mit _nicht_ ist es in jedem Fall vertrauter.

Comment: Der Satz hört sich ohne perfekt aber auch nicht richtig an. Du musst ja eigentlich das helfen beendet haben um ins Bett gehen zu können.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde sagen, dass deine Beispiele spezielle Formen des Temporalsatzes sind. Hier eines Temporalsatzes mit einer Verneinung und einer zusätzlichen konditionalen Bedeutung.

Verneinte Satzgefüge mit *bevor* (und auch *ehe*) haben oft eine konditionale (an eine Bedingung geknüpfte) Bedeutung. Der Nebensatz gibt eine Bedingung an, die erfüllt sein muss, bevor der Fall des Hauptsatzes eintritt (… erst das, dann das …). Dabei muss der Hauptsatz verneint sein, während der Nebensatz mit oder ohne *nicht* stehen kann, ohne dass ein Bedeutungsunterschied entsteht.

Bsp:

- Ich bezahle nichts, bevor ich (nicht) eine detaillierte Abrechnung erhalten habe.
- Bevor ich (nicht) eine detaillierte Abrechnung erhalten habe, zahle ich nichts.

Die Verwendung dieses *nicht* im Nebensatz wird von einigen als unmgangssprachlich oder falsch angesehen, erklärt sich aber aus de speziellen konditionalen Bedeutung von *solange nicht*; *wenn nicht* dieser Konditionen und kann daher als gültig angewendet werden, ohne dass ein ungewöhnlich klingender Satz entsteht.

Bsp:

- Du erhältst kein Geld, *bevor/ehe* du *nicht* sagst, was du damit machen willst 
  **versus** 
  Du erhältst kein Geld *bevor/ehe* du sagst, was du damit machen willst

→ beides möglich

Answer (score 1):

Ich empfinde die Verwendung des *nicht* in dem Beispielsatz in der Frage als falsch, aber hauptsächlich wegen der verwendeten Zeit. Für mich wären

> …, solange ich nicht allen geholfen habe.

oder

> …, bevor ich allen geholfen habe.

möglich,

oder auch

> …, wenn ich nicht allen geholfen habe.

Oder ohne Verneinung:

> Ich kann erst ins Bett gehen, wenn ich allen geholfen habe.

Mit allen diesen Varianten ist klargestellt, dass das Helfen abgeschlossen ist, bevor man ins Bett geht.